# java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger doesn't override equals method just as java.lang.Integer?

Tags: java, concurrency

I can came across comparing `AtomicInteger` instances in my code and found no equals methods overridden. However `java.lang.Integer` does provide implementation for `equals`/`hashCode` methods.

The users shall take alternate route of comparing int from `get()` or `getInt()` methods.

My question is what stopped Sir. Doug Lea to not override `equals`/`hashCode` methods? I am sure there are valid reasons for it which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Objects of **AtomicInteger** are **Mutable** and its enough hint to not override hashcode and equals.

Its not advisable to use mutable objects as keys for Maps and hence no reason to override hashcode and hence equals.